# 2002 BMW 745LI Stripped Fill Plug --What Else?

Tags: transmission, bmw, 745li

BMW 2002 745LI striped fill plug that is stuck and I'm a female...not super strong arms like the gents. I'm willing to use Dremel to cut a seam at 12 o'clock to use a flat head but its so tight in there. Drilling a hole presents just about the same problem so I have a flexible extension...kinda scared to drill hole.  So...I've rigged a hand pump with rubber stopper to insert where drain plug is after draining fluid. Then pump in the fluid and quickly replace drain plug.  My friend says I'm going to be right back to not enough fluid.  So how about securing the rubber stopper long enough to get it to a  shop cause i can't get  flatbed for tow.  If this is a go idea, ideas on how to secure to ensure staying in place while driving carefully to the shop? Would hate to go dry in the middle of the road.

Lastly, I don't believe I've updated software on this car for trans or anything else. Would this stop it from moving?  It goes into gear and sounds great, looks great.....does not pull off or reverse without high acceleration which I don't want to continue doing.  I've had no issues like noise or lunging or nothing.  Im hoping like hell it is fluid though it is very dark brown but I don't see any shavings in the fluid (I have not removed the pan). Emptied drain; yielded about 2 liters.  This car's capacity is 9 liters and I think the pan holds 4 liters.  I think low 2 liters enough for my symptoms. Without fill plug I'd be guessing but I'm prepared with 6 liters. Car sitting for about a year.